# How can I access some json value dynamicailly with jquery templates

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I have the following json and suppose that I can't modify it:

```
{
    "structure": [
        {"property": "propA"},
        {"property": "propB"}
    ],
    "data": {
        "propA": 7,
        "propB": "something"
    }
}
```

Now the template:

```
{{each structure}}
        <span>${data.$value.property}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

What I want to achieve is that where I do `${data.$value.property}}` have the same result as if I do `${data.propA}`

**Issue: I don't know that "propA" exists whithin the "data" json. I have to access that part dinamically**

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span>${data[$value.property]}}</span>
```

Comment: but that would print "propA" when I need to print "7" (data.propA)